# pread returns 0 when it's not supposed to?

Tags: c, file-transfer, chunking

I am writing a file transfer program.  However for some reason `pread` is returning `0` despite not being at the end of the file.  Can anyone take a look at my code and see the problem?  It works perfectly with `fread`.

```
        int file;
        unsigned int size = selfp->intdata;
        file=open(str, O_RDONLY); 
        char buf[1024];

        printf("filename = %s \n", str);//prints file name requested
        printf("buffer = %s \n", buf);//prints nothing currently
        printf("offset = %d \n",atoi(chunkIndex)*CHUNK);//prints 0 for first chunk
        printf("CHUNK = %d \n", CHUNK);//prints 1024
        int myoffset = atoi(chunkIndex)*CHUNK; 
        int dataSize=pread(file, buf, sizeof buf, myoffset);
        printf("%d\n", dataSize);//returns 0

        close(file);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to verify that your `atoi(chunkIndex)*CHUNK` is not at the end of your particular file ?

Comment: You're not check if `open` succeeded or if your call to `atoi` did what you think it did.  Please provide sample input as well or we can't answer your question.

Comment: Try adding file and myoffset to the output.

Comment: nos - atoi(chunkIndex)*CHUNK returns 0 so it is not at the end of the program.   @Ed S. - file returns 4 and atoi returned 0m which is what the first chunk index should be.  Michael Krelin - myoffset returns 0 and file returns 4.   Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: It won't help that you're mixing up `CHUNK`, `1024` and `sizeof(buf)`.  `char buf[CHUNK];` would be an improvement. But I think your real problem is that you're not checking for `open()` errors .

Comment: well, I suppose my point is that `pread` is almost certainly doing *exactly* what it is supposed to be doing.  That function is battle tested; your code isn't.  So, assuming your code is to blame, it would help to have sample input, i.e., the file you are reading.  And again, check for success after calling `open`.

Comment: What's your platform and compiler? A broken `pread` function is unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: I think that @EdS. is correct; unless you're working in a non-standard OS, a broken `pread` would be kind of shocking.  Have you tried seeing if you can actually seek to your desired offset?  Print out the result of `lseek(file, myoffset, SEEK_SET)` and see if it matches `myoffset`.  If you use `fdopen` to create a file handle from the descriptor, does `fread` work as you expect?